# Identify a story about a plant that becomes conscious and takes over a planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A seed lands on Earth in a desert or plain. The story was told through the point of view of a plant, and later a crow. The plant is conscious and eventually kills the crow, then takes over the planet by spreading seed I think. It was a short story.

Answer (score 14):

"Seeds of the Dusk" by Raymond Z. Gallun?

A [description](http://ezinearticles.com/?Mood-and-Action-in-a-Tale-of-the-Far-Future---Seeds-of-the-Dusk&id=832911) found online:

> Its 31 pages give us an insight into the lives and fates of three species: an alien invading plant intelligence; the descendants of crows; and the descendants of Man. Into this short tale are packed great events and an unforgettable, haunting mood which is well encapsulated in the title.

Comment: That's definitely it. I read this story in the anthology 'Adventures in Time and Space', a fantastic collection of gold and silver age SF.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish gymbrall isn't the OP (nor is there any reason to think that both accounts are the same person).